# Why do I get a 500 error when requesting /cgi-bin/php

Tags: php, apache, cgi

Why do I get a 500 error when requesting /cgi-bin/php

I have php installed as a cgi process, it works fine, unless I request that specific url.

This is my conf:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    IdleTimeout 3600
    ProcessLifeTime 7200
    MaxProcessCount 64
    DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 8
    IPCConnectTimeout 300
    IPCCommTimeout 7200
    BusyTimeout 300

    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /opt/php/cgi/

    <Directory "/opt/php">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't think `php` matches `.+\.php`...

Comment: Unless you have a file in your cgi-bin called `php`, you won't get a page from the server.